# Disable submit button on file input validation error using krajee file-input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `plugins.krajee.com/file-input` and I can't find a way of disabling the upload or submit button of my form when a validation error occurs like `minImageWidth` is exceeded.

```
$('.file').fileinput({
        language: 'en',
        showUpload: false,
        allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif'],
        maxFileSize:1024,
        minImageWidth:286,
        minImageHeight:322
     });
```

How do I use `$('.file').fileinput('disable');` when image width minimum setting returns the validation error?

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?

Comment: I think i found a workaround on it, are you looking for that solution. its been a while though..

Comment: yes, could you please share the workaround?

Comment: The plugin has since changed alot, am now seeing the use of $('#input-id').on('fileerror', function(event, data, msg) {
   console.log(data.id);
   console.log(data.index);
   console.log(data.file);
   console.log(data.reader);
   console.log(data.files);
   // get message
   alert(msg);
});
at http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#file-events

Comment: i cant locate my old laptop to access the solution i used then, but i guess it would not help now that there is a new version..